# What part is this 2x2 curved slope?

Tags: piece-information

This is the piece I'm looking for:

[image]

I need the part number.

Comment: Welcome to Bricks.SE!

Comment: The part number is in the picture.

Answer (score 3):

That is [15068 PLATE W. BOW 2X2X2/3](https://brickset.com/parts/design-15068):

[image: Part image from Brickset]

Comment: Or as Bricklink calls it: Slope, Curved 2x2 No Studs.